# Laravel Sanctum SPA catch() at the end of a promise chain won't catch error

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to do a simple login page using Laravel, React and Sanctum SPA authentication. My problem is that I get an uncaught error from an axios promise even though I end my promise chain with catch(), and I don't understand nearly enough about Laravel or Axios to find out why.

Console:

```
app.js:197 POST http://localhost:8000/api/login 403 (Forbidden)

app.js:607 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (app.js:607)
    at settle (app.js:878)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:82)
```

Request:

```
api.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
    api.post('/api/login', {
    name: username,
    password: password
    }
    ).then((response) => {
    //Works if I enter the correct credentials
    console.log('works')
    })
    }).catch(error => {
    //Won't catch the error if I enter wrong credentials
    setError('error')
})
```

Laravel controller:

```
public function logIn(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->only('name', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return response()->json([], 204);
    }

    return response()->json([], 403);
}
```

A workaround I found is to not return 403 but 200 with an error message and to branch the code accordingly. But I find this rather baffling since several examples of Sanctum SPA authentication I have seen use the original way.

Comment: The inner response isn't part of the overall promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you chain your promises like below:

```
api.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
    .then(() => api.post('/api/login', { 
        name: username,
        password: password}))
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('works')
    }).catch(error => {
    //Won't catch the error if I enter wrong credentials
        setError('error')
    })
```

Note how the `api.post` result is returned and the `then` is chained after the outer `then` rather than inside the callback. This will allow the `catch` to catch any errors either from the `api.get` or `api.post`